# Segmentation fault disappear with gdb in ubunutu on windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, ubuntu, gdb

I've been tasked with locating the bug in the following code, and fixing it:

```
/* $Id: count-words.c 858 2010-02-21 10:26:22Z tolpin $ */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* return string "word" if the count is 1 or "words" otherwise */
char *words(int count) {
  char *words = "words";
  if(count==1) 
    words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
  return words;
}

/* print a message reportint the number of words */
int print_word_count(char **argv) {
  int count = 0;
  char **a = argv;
  while(*(a++))
    ++count;
  printf("The sentence contains %d %s.\n", count, words(count));
  return count;
}

/* print the number of words in the command line and return the number as the exit code */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  return print_word_count(argv+1);
}
```

The program works well for every number of words given to it, except for one word. Running it with `./count-words hey` will cause a segmentation fault.

I'm running my code on the Linux subsystem on Windows 10 (that's what I understand it is called at least...), with the official Ubuntu app.

When running the program from terminal, I do get the segmentation fault, but using gdb, for some reason the program works fine:

```
(gdb) r hey
Starting program: .../Task 0/count-words hey
The sentence contains 1 word.
[Inferior 1 (process 87) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

After adding a breakpoint on line 9 and stepping through the code, I get this:

```
(gdb) b 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400579: file count-words.c, line 9.
(gdb) r hey
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/tfrei/Google Drive/BGU/Semester F/Computer Architecture/Labs/Lab 2/Task 0/count-words hey

Breakpoint 1, words (count=1) at count-words.c:9
9         if(count==1)
(gdb) s
10          words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
(gdb) s
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:66
66      ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
67      in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
(gdb) s
68      in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
(gdb)
```

The weird thing is that when I ran the same thing from a "true" Ubuntu (using a virtual machine on Windows 10), the segmentation fault did happen on gdb.

I tend to believe that the reason for this is somehow related to my runtime environment (the "Ubuntu on Windows" thing), but could not find anything that will help me.

This is my makefile:

```
all: 
    gcc -g -Wall -o count-words count-words.c 

clean: 
    rm -f count-words
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `char *words = "words";` is a pointer to a string literal, modifying it is undefined behaviour and leads in most cases into a segfault, as it is read-only memory. You cannot modify it.

Comment: Do Not Write a Code like this.

Comment: Pablo thanks, but I'm not asking about the bug itself , and why the segmentation fault happened. I'm asking why it didn't happen with gdb. Sorry if that was not clear enough.

Comment: Michi, what is the problem?

Comment: @tfreifeld Do you know what Literal Strings are?

Comment: Before you use a debugger you should use a memory tool like VALGRIND. By the way, you should definitely turn on your compiler Flags.

Comment: Strange, I ran the exact same code on my gdb and I got `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault` on line 8

Comment: @tfreifeld use “-Wwrite-strings”

Comment: @pablo why is that Strange? Should not happen?

Comment: @Michi I find it strange that the OP's gdb did not show the segfault.

Comment: Could it be that the Linux subsystem in windows 10 does not treat string literals as read-only memory?

Comment: That's UB. Don't ask for an explanation of why faulty code sometimes works.

Comment: There are better ways to pluralise, for example `char *plural[] = { "", "s" }; printf("%d word%s", count, plural[count != 1]);`

Comment: that code may or may not segfault, depending on how and where the string literal is stored.  As pointed out, code that modifies the string literal has undefined behavior (I.e. UB).  Also, in your gdb trace, you won't be able to step into strlen.  But if you step over if with `n` what do you get when you examine the variable `words`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking why it didn't happen with gdb

It *did* happen with GDB, when run on a real (or virtual) UNIX system.

It didn't happen when running under the weird "Ubuntu on Windows" environment, because that environment is doing crazy sh*t. In particular, for some reason the Windows subsystem maps usually readonly sections (`.rodata`, and probably `.text` as well) with writable permissions (which is why the program no longer crashes), but only when you run the program under debugger.

I don't know why exactly Windows does that.

Note that debuggers *do* need to write to (readonly) `.text` section in order to insert breakpoints. On a real UNIX system, this is achieved by `ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, ...)` system call, which updates the readonly page, *but leaves it readonly* for the inferior (being debugged) process.

I am guessing that Windows is imperfectly emulating this behavior (in particular does not write-protect the page after updating it).

P.S. In general, using "Ubuntu on Windows" to learn Ubuntu is going to be full of gotchas like this one. You will likely be *much* better off using a virtual machine instead.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I guess I will have to settle to the VM (which works relatively slow for me, although I had given it plenty of RAM... don't know why it is slow, but I didn't give it a lot of thought. that's why I chose to work with Ubuntu on Windows instead).
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This function is wrong

```
char *words(int count) {
  char *words = "words";
  if(count==1) 
    words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
  return words;
}
```

The pointer `words` points to the string literal `"words"`. Modifying a string
literal is undefined behaviour and in most system string literals are stored in
read-only memory, so doing

```
    words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
```

will lead into a segfault. That's the behaviour you see in Ubuntu. I don't know
where strings literals are stored in windows executables, but modifying a string
literal is undefined behaviour and anything can happen and it's pointless to try
to deduce why sometimes things work and why sometimes things don't work. That's
the nature of undefined behaviour.

**edit**

> Pablo thanks, but I'm not asking about the bug itself , and why the segmentation fault happened. I'm asking why it didn't happen with gdb. Sorry if that was not clear enough.

I don't know why it doesn't happent to your, but when I run your code on my gdb I get:

```
Reading symbols from ./bug...done.
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6fc: file bug.c, line 8.
(gdb) r hey
Starting program: /tmp/bug hey

Breakpoint 1, words (count=1) at bug.c:8
8       words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554713 in words (count=1) at bug.c:8
8       words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
(gdb)
```

Comment: “but modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour and anything can happen.”, maybe the OP gets lucky and see how his PC burns. He will never code like that.

Comment: That would have been fun to see ;)
Actually, I didn't write that code. It was written by my course instructor, to serve as an exercise in pointers and gdb debugging. Some of the point of it was to teach not to write code like that.